# fatal: pathspec 'README.txt' did not match any files

Tags: git

Really getting stuck on this one.  I've googled a lot and can't figure out what I've done wrong...

I'm trying to create a new file, via the `git add README.txt` command in terminal...

(So far I've created a new folder `Fundamentals`. Created a sub-folder `git-practice`.  And created a git repo via `git init` command)

However, when I try and add a file in `fundamentals/git-practice`, i get the following error..

```
fatal: pathspec 'README.txt' did not match any files
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong.. everything seems to make sense.  Here's the code:

```
Reenas-MBP:~ reenaverma$ cd ~

Reenas-MBP:~ reenaverma$ ls
72.png          GitHub          flask-workshop
Applications        Library         fundamentals
Creative Cloud Files    Movies          funny_things
Desktop         Music           get-pip.py
Documents       Pictures        world
Downloads       Public          wwlc
Dropbox         Retrieved Contents

Reenas-MBP:~ reenaverma$ cd fundamentals

Reenas-MBP:fundamentals reenaverma$ ls
git-practice

Reenas-MBP:fundamentals reenaverma$ cd git-practice

Reenas-MBP:git-practice reenaverma$ ls -a
.   ..  .git

Reenas-MBP:git-practice reenaverma$ pwd
/Users/reenaverma/fundamentals/git-practice

Reenas-MBP:git-practice reenaverma$ git add README.txt
fatal: pathspec 'README.txt' did not match any files

Reenas-MBP:git-practice reenaverma$
```

Comment: Did you create a file named `README.txt`? If you are using `git bash`, type `ls` in the directory where your git repo lives to see what files are there.

Comment: Make this first: `echo "# git-practice" >> README.txt` and then `git add README.txt`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> fatal: pathspec 'README.txt' did not match any files

You get this error because there is no file named `README.txt` in the current directory. Git is in the business of managing files that you create with other programs, usually a text editor or IDE. `git add` only adds the file to the index. It does not create any files directly. You need to use another tool to do so. Use your favorite text editor (I suggest Notepad++, Sublime Text 3, or Atom) and create a file with some text.

Answer (score 23):

> I'm trying to create a new file, via the 'git add README.txt' command in terminal...

`git add` does not create a new file. It adds an existing file to be indexed by git. You'll need to create the file first.

Comment: Can you please tell how to create one via the terminal, in mac?

Comment: @javan.rajpopat really? just `touch README.txt`

Answer (score 14):

Just type in your terminal (e.g. in git bash):

```
git >> README.md
git add README.md
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and after typing ls I had git display all the files I had in the folder, then I found that I had saved the readme file as readme.txt.txt. Hence I had to rename the file to readme.txt and then I was able to add it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me

```
git add README.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I do following this command (windows10) in terminal and everthing is working

- > git init
  >   git add README.txt
  >   git commit -m "first commit"
  >   git remote add origin https://github.com/your_github/github_project.git So I create my token in github then git push origin master